# Logstash + nginx: Fields wont be added

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm going to Setup my own ELK Server to centralize logging. So far so good.

I Setup docker-compose.yml to run the ELK stack and another docker-compose.yml to run filebeat, which will watch logfiles, add env + tags and sent to logstash. The parsing should be made in logstash.

filebeat.yml

```
name: xyz

fields:
  env: xyz

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["xyz:5044"]

filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    fields:
      app_id: default
      type: nginx-access
    tags:
      - nginx
      - access
    paths:
      - /logs/nginx/access.log*
  - input_type: log
    fields:
      app_id: default
      type: nginx-error
    tags:
      - nginx
      - error
    paths:
      - /logs/nginx/error.log*
```

and here's the logstash.yml

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  if ["nginx"] in [tags] and ["access"] in [tags] {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
      match => { "message" => "%{NGINXACCESS}" }
    }

    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The nginx-pattern is here

```
NGUSERNAME [a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+
NGUSER %{NGUSERNAME}
NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)\" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-))\" (?:%{QS:referree}) %{QS:agent}
```

I tested the Expression on grokconstructor.appspot.com and it hits.

Here's a demo line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2017:13:49:31 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586" "-"
```

But no fields where added

[image]

I think maybe my "if" is wrong, but I tried several alternatives... nothing helped.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by removing the if, then adding the conditions one by one. That is start with

```
["nginx"] in [tags]
```

and if that works, then go in for

```
["nginx"] in [tags] and ["access"] in [tags]
```

Alternatively you could try using

```
"nginx" in [tags] and "access" in [tags]
```

**UPDATE:**

To used fields.type = nginx-access, try

```
"nginx-access" in [fields][type]
```

Comment: thanks man :) ```if "nginx" in [tags] and "access" in [tags] {``` works fine

Comment: Cool! happy to have been of help.

Comment: any idea how the "if" condition has to be to fit ```fields.type = nginx-access```?